# Python : range between dates when range field has time

Tags: python, django

I want to make a range between 2 dates and my range field has the time

```
damage_list = Damage.objects.filter(entry_date__range=(fdate, tdate))
```

fdate and tdate are dates ('YYYY-mm-dd') and entry_date has time.
How can I range all the records of the tdate ?

Thanks in advance

Kostas

Comment: Should work like that, the only problem is whether you want to include/exclude the boundaries `fdate`, `tdate`.

Comment: What should happen if the `entry_date` is `2018-07-30 10:00:00` for example, and `tdate` is `2018-07-30`? Should we include the item? Or not?

Comment: Yes. I want to truncate time. I did it by adding a day to tdate (+ timedelta(days=1) ) but I don't think it is the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add time to `fdate` and `tdate` using `datetime.datetime.combine`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date
>>> datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.min.time())
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 30, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.max.time())
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 30, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
```

Applying the minimum time to `fdate` and the maximum time to `tdate` will ensure that the time fits into those boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to take the *date* part into account, you can use the `__date` lookup:

```
damage_list = Damage.objects.filter(entry_date__date__range=(fdate, tdate))
```

This will result in a query like:

```
SELECT damage.*
FROM damage
WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`entry_date`, 'UTC', 'UTC'))
      BETWEEN 2018-01-01 AND 2018-07-01
```

or in case we do not use timezones (`USE_TZ = False` in the settings):

```
SELECT damage.*
FROM damage
WHERE DATE(`entry_date`, 'UTC', 'UTC') BETWEEN 2018-01-01 AND 2018-07-01
```

Where here `2018-01-01` and `2018-07-01` are sample `fdate` and `tdate`s.

Note that in case of timezones, the story can even get more complex, since there can be a difference between the *local* date, and the UTC date.

Comment: I kind of like your answer better...led me down the path of "how does he know about that??". Welp, here's the full list of field lookups for OP and future visitors: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Comment: @wholevinski: thanks, did +1 for your approach :). The lookups can be useful in writing short filter statements in a more declarative way.

Comment: It doesn't work. Do I have to format fdate and tdate in YYYY-mm-dd format?

Comment: @kpk: that depends on the formats you have selected in the settings. But I validated that `'2018-01-01'`, etc. work with default settings in Django-2.0. With `USE_I18N = True` however, it will use your "locale".

Comment: @kpk: see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATE_INPUT_FORMATS Without tweaking `YYYY-mm-dd` is the first format used. You can also pass a `date(..)` object (this of course needs some formatting), but if your settings allow it, it should parse this format.